# YAJSW window service did not start

Tags: java, service, yajsw

I have one Java application and I want that it should run as window services. I have chosen YAJSW for this. I have run its GetConfig.bat with my Java process ID and it has generated it config file. I have placed the User name and password in the config file and run the runConsole.bat.  My jar file run successfully and I have seen in the log file of JAJSW which I have print out in my application. Now when I run installService.bat file. It successfully generate service but when I go the window services and run the that window service it show the error :  `"error 1053: The service did not respond to the start  or control request in the timely fashion"`

Can someone help me, how can I solve this problem.

Comment: Post your wrapper.conf please

Comment: what about the resolution of the issue?

Answer (score 1):

Did you enter a username and/or password under `wrapper.app.account` or `wrapper.ntservice.account` (with corresponding password) in the wrapper configuration file?

If so, try commenting them out, maybe you have a problem with the user-account.

Comment: I have run along the same problem, have not filled in the username or password, any other suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the issue is related to have both, Java 7 and Java 8. Please check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/37047073/1666929

Answer (score 0):

Set the path to the java.exe in your service

Firstly get the path to the bin folder where java.exe is in.
Then open your service and copy the path executable > java.exe....

```
sc config <servicename> binPath="FULLPATHTOBIN"+"\"+"PATHTOEXECUTABLE"
```