# Any alternative of YAJSW to run jar as window service

Tags: java, windows, service, jar, yajsw

I have followed exactly same steps as mentioned in their documentation. But, getting error when trying to start service. "Error 1053: Service did not respond to the start or control request in a timely fashion"

Anyone help me to resolve this issue or suggestion any alternative to run jar file as window service will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Nobody has answered this question yet :( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20878052/yajsw-window-service-did-not-start

Answer (score 2):

Maybe your problem is related to have Java 7 and Java 8 installed. Removing either version solve the issue.

There is an alternative solution described [here](https://sourceforge.net/p/yajsw/bugs/114/) that allows to keep both version in the machine.

Comment: Thanks, this works.Whats worse is that there is no indication of what the problem was.Just won't start.

Answer (score 0):

Downgrading to Java 7 resolved this issue for me. Literally removing Java 8. Seems to be a bug in the YAJSW,

Any other solution is kindly welcomed

Answer (score 0):

I am having the same problem, have successfully installed a Network-Service
but not able to start the service from YAJSW. And when i try to start it from the UI i get the same error code "error 1053".

The problem arises when i include this line: `wrapper.ntservice.account=NT AUTHORITY\\NetworkService` commenting this out works